# When generate crystal report, its giving error : QueryEngine error: verify database failed

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting error while generating PDF and HTML from Crystal report.
The same is working fine in SIT, Only UAT gives me problem.

Here is the error.

```
164143 [12/06/2020 13:26:30:571] [default task-3] ERROR com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine  - QueryEngine error: verify database failed.
164165 [12/06/2020 13:26:30:593] [default task-3] ERROR com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition  - com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.driverImpl.m: JDBC Error: Function "GET_DISPLAY_AMT" not found; SQL statement:
```

When i execute the SQL in SQL client, i didn't get any issues.

Appreciate someone help on this.

```
Application Platform: 
EAP 7.1
RHEL Linux
Oracle : 12c
```

Comment: Hi, did you check the function get_display_amt? it seems that you don't have access to it or doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi,  When i run the SQL in SQL developer its getting executed successfully. no issues in SQL.